# Error with image display

Tags: php, html

Please check below code and help me out if anything is going wrong in image display code
        
        
        Untitled Document

```
    <body>
<p>how to display image</p>
<p>image is not seeingd</p>

    <?php
     $con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     $d=  mysql_select_db("matrimonial",$con);
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $sql  = "select * from advertiesment where S_NO ='1'" or    die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

    if($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

      $image = $rows['filepath'];
     echo "<img style='width:150px;height:150px' src='$image'>";
     echo "<br>";
    }
    ?><p>how to display image</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: never use a php variable inside a single quote so make your document like this echo '<img style="width:150px;height:150px" src="$image">' and if $image have a correct path to your desired image file it will be displayed properly.

Comment: <?php
$con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        $d=  mysql_select_db("matrimonial",$con);
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  $sql  = "select * from advertiesment where S_NO ='6'" or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

print_r($rows);

 $image = $rows['filepath'] . '/' . $rows['filename'];
  echo "<img style='width:150px;height:150px' src='".$image."'>";
    echo "<br>";

?>

Comment: **not display code**

Comment: you are missing the file name as you are just display image path in img src so you have to put $image = $rows['filepath'].'/'.$rows['filename']; than  echo '<img style="width:150px;height:150px" src="$image">'  and to debug it just look at your page source and see in img tag src what it is showing there ? i'm sure its only showing the path whichi is in $image not the image name which is in $rows['filename'];

Comment: <?php
$con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      $d=mysql_select_db("matrimonial",$con);

$sqlimage  = "SELECT * FROM advertiesment where `S_NO` ='10'";
$imageresult1 = mysql_query($sqlimage);
if (!$imageresult1) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
{
 $image = $rows['img_path'].'/'.$rows['img_name']; 
 echo '<img style="width:150px;height:150px" src="$image">' ;
    echo "<img style='width:150px;height:150px' src='$image' >";
    echo "<br>";
 echo $rows['title'];

}?> after all it's  not display

Comment: after running the script goto page source of your document and you will see the error there or you will see what src is shown with your img tag .

Comment: photo1/paathshala.jp/paathshala.jpg

Comment: and what is the exact path to paathshala.jpg file kindly paste it here and make sure you have same path saved in img_path of your db and same name im your img_name of your db.

Comment: at first src "$image"

Comment: in the database column ,img_name=paathshala.jpg  and               img_path= photo1/paathshala.jpg

Comment: and in img_path image is saved as photo1/paathshala.jp

Comment: oOk than you don't need to use imag_name in your php as you are saving path to photo1/paathshala.jpg, now what is the complete path of your paathshala.jpg in your project. may be u need to go back one level so you have to put ../ before or / before photo1/paathshala.jpg to get the exact path. if its saving as paathshala.jp it means length of your varchar is less than the string of photo1/paathshala.jpg file that's why its .jp at the end not .jpg

Comment: thanks sir  i have problem in varchr its size was only 20 now i gave it 100 so it run

Comment: but sir how  i should kept varchar length for any image ?

Comment: if you are not sure about the length of your string than use it as full 255 in your varchar length or don't use long filenames. because path will be same but filename can increase the length of your string which will not fit in varchar so either use TEXT type or make varchar 255 length.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

The condition is bad. If you have  more results from SQL query,you need to use `while`.

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {...
```

If you have only one, remove just `if`:

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo ...
```

**EDIT:**

```
$image = $rows['filepath'] . '/' . $rows['filename'];
```

Comment: <?php
$con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        $d=  mysql_select_db("matrimonial",$con);
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  $sql  = "select * from advertiesment where S_NO ='1'" or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);



 $image = $rows['filepath'];
  echo "<img style='width:150px;height:150px' src='".$image."'>";
    echo "<br>";

?>

Comment: @RahulKashyap: what `print_r($rows)` says?

Comment: Array ( [S_NO] => 1 [title] => i want to update ima [ad_name] => sdf [mn] => dfg [duration] => sdf [act_date] => 2015-05-12 [ex_date] => 2015-05-13 [business_ad] => sfsff [filename] => previous.png [filetype] => image/png [filepath] => advertiesment/previo )

Comment: @RahulKashyap: you forgot put there `filename`. See the update above.

Comment: $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  $sql  = "select * from advertiesment where S_NO ='1'" or die(mysql_error());

Comment: and my file name is filepath (image in filepath)

Comment: title is only title name (i want update ima ) it's only text for title

Comment: @RahulKashyap: change $image variable like I've updated above. The image full filename is `$filepath/$filename`.

Comment: Array ( [S_NO] => 6 [title] => rahul [ad_name] => message [mn] => 231231 [duration] => 3 hours [act_date] => 2015-05-05 [ex_date] => 2015-05-12 [business_ad] => 91 pata nahi [filename] => images (2).jpg [filetype] => image/jpeg [filepath] => advertiesment/images )

Comment: Array ( [S_NO] => 6 [title] => rahul [ad_name] => message [mn] => 231231 [duration] => 3 hours [act_date] => 2015-05-05 [ex_date] => 2015-05-12 [business_ad] => 91 pata nahi [filename] => images (2).jpg [filetype] => image/jpeg [filepath] => advertiesment/images )

Answer (score 0):

Dont use :

```
if($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

      $image = $rows['filepath'];
     echo "<img style='width:150px;height:150px' src='$image'>";
     echo "<br>";
    }
```

use this  directly

$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

```
  $image = $rows['filepath'];
 echo "<img style='width:150px;height:150px' src='$image'>";
 echo "<br>";
```